# How to merge two data frames on common columns in R with sum of others?

Tags: r, merge, plyr

R Version 2.11.1 32-bit on Windows 7

I got two data sets: data_A and data_B:

#### data_A

```
USER_A USER_B ACTION
1      11     0.3
1      13     0.25
1      16     0.63
1      17     0.26
2      11     0.14
2      14     0.28
```

#### data_B

```
USER_A USER_B ACTION
1      13     0.17
1      14     0.27
2      11     0.25
```

Now I want to add the ACTION of data_B to the data_A if their USER_A and USER_B are equal. As the example above, the result would be:

#### data_A

```
USER_A USER_B ACTION
1      11     0.3
1      13     0.25+0.17
1      16     0.63
1      17     0.26
2      11     0.14+0.25
2      14     0.28
```

So how could I achieve it?

Comment: Normally, I'd use awk or perl for this. Would such a solution be ok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge and sum two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468502/how-to-merge-and-sum-two-data-frames)

Comment: While the above linked question is newer, it has more a number of nicer, more current approaches.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `ddply` in package `plyr` and combine it with `merge`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(merge(data_A, data_B, all.x=TRUE), 
  .(USER_A, USER_B), summarise, ACTION=sum(ACTION))
```

Notice that `merge` is called with the parameter `all.x=TRUE` - this returns all of the values in the first data.frame passed to `merge`, i.e. data_A:

```
  USER_A USER_B ACTION
1      1     11   0.30
2      1     13   0.25
3      1     16   0.63
4      1     17   0.26
5      2     11   0.14
6      2     14   0.28
```

Comment: That output isn't quite what the OP had - notice you have one extra row than the OP wanted. We need `data_A` but with an update to two of the `ACTION` entries. The equivalent base R of your answer would be: `aggregate(ACTION ~ USER_B + USER_A, data = rbind(data_A, data_B), FUN = sum)[, c(2,1,3)]` but I discounted this because it wasn't an update of `data_A`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson  Thank you for spotting this.  I have now modified the code to use merge, rather than rbind.

Comment: Dies quick on two sets of 3M rows each after consuming 2Gb of ram.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov If you want faster processing with lower memory consumption, try the data.table package

Comment: am I missing something? OP asked the action column value to be summed, but this answer doesn't?

Comment: @kevin0228ca If I replace the "merge" with rbind I get something that works.

Answer (score 16):

This sort of thing is quite easy to do with a database-like operation. Here I use package `sqldf` to do a left (outer) join and then summarise the resulting object:

```
require(sqldf)
tmp <- sqldf("select * from data_A left join data_B using (USER_A, USER_B)")
```

This results in:

```
> tmp
  USER_A USER_B ACTION ACTION
1      1     11   0.30     NA
2      1     13   0.25   0.17
3      1     16   0.63     NA
4      1     17   0.26     NA
5      2     11   0.14   0.25
6      2     14   0.28     NA
```

Now we just need sum the two `ACTION` columns:

```
data_C <- transform(data_A, ACTION = rowSums(tmp[, 3:4], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
> data_C
  USER_A USER_B ACTION
1      1     11   0.30
2      1     13   0.42
3      1     16   0.63
4      1     17   0.26
5      2     11   0.39
6      2     14   0.28
```

This can be done using standard R function `merge`:

```
> merge(data_A, data_B, by = c("USER_A","USER_B"), all.x = TRUE)
  USER_A USER_B ACTION.x ACTION.y
1      1     11     0.30       NA
2      1     13     0.25     0.17
3      1     16     0.63       NA
4      1     17     0.26       NA
5      2     11     0.14     0.25
6      2     14     0.28       NA
```

So we can replace the `sqldf()` call above with:

```
tmp <- merge(data_A, data_B, by = c("USER_A","USER_B"), all.x = TRUE)
```

whilst the second line using `transform()` remains the same.

Comment: You could simply add these in the SQL query, and then there's no need for the `transform`.  *e.g.* `SELECT A.USER_A, B.USER_B, A.ACTION + B.ACTION AS ACTION FROM data_A A INNER JOIN data_B B ON A.USER_A = B.USER_B`

Comment: This answer works while I tried a lot with accepted answer without achieving...+1

Answer (score 3):

We can use {powerjoin}:

```
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(
  data_A,  data_B, by = c("USER_A", "USER_B"), 
  conflict = ~ .x + ifelse(is.na(.y), 0, .y)
)
#>   USER_A USER_B ACTION
#> 1      1     11   0.30
#> 2      1     13   0.42
#> 3      1     16   0.63
#> 4      1     17   0.26
#> 5      2     11   0.39
#> 6      2     14   0.28
```

In case of conflict, the function fed to the `conflict` argument will be used
on pairs of conflicting columns.

We can also use `sum(,  na.rm = TRUE)` row-wise for the same effect :

```
power_left_join(data_A,data_B, by = c("USER_A", "USER_B"), 
                conflict = rw ~ sum(.x, .y, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I really like this nice option, thanks. Also possible in case of incomparable 'by' to sum nicely: ~ifelse(is.na(.x),0,.x)+ifelse(is.na(.y),0,.y)