# how to migrate multiple data frames into one in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple data frames, for example:
data frame 1

```
  V1 V2
1 Charlie 30
2 Tom 50
3 Anna 20
```

data frame 2

```
  V1 V2
1 Tom 30
2 Anna 10
3 Julia 60
```

how can I migrate these data frame into same one and add the second columns if the first column value was same:

```
  V1 V2
1 Charlie 30
2 Tom 80
3 Anna 30
4 Julia 60
```

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5769320/

Answer (score 3):

We can use `tidyverse`.  We use `bind_rows` to bind the multiple datasets together, then grouped by 'V1', get the `sum` of 'V2'

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(df1,df2) %>%
        group_by(V1) %>% 
        summarise(V2 = sum(V2))
```

---

Or using `data.table`, we can place the datasets in a `list`, use `rbindlist` to bind the datasets in the `list`, then grouped by 'V1', get the `sum` of 'V2'

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[, .(V2 = sum(V2)), by = V1]
```

---

Or with `base R`, by `rbind`ing the datasets, use `aggregate` to get the `sum` of 'V2' grouped by 'V1'

```
aggregate(V2 ~V1, rbind(df1, df2), FUN = sum)
#       V1 V2
#1    Anna 30
#2 Charlie 30
#3   Julia 60
#4     Tom 80
```